# How to use multiple formats for a single logger

Tags: python, logging

I have a module that outputs data to the console and to a log file.  I would like the console output to have a simple `'%(message)s'` format but in the log file I would like to add the timestamp `'%(asctime)s - %(message)s'`.  How does one setup the handlers to send a different format to the console than it does to the log file?  The methods I have tried result in sending *both* messages to the console.

Below is one example of what does NOT work:

```
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    root.addHandler(console)
    if sysout:
        handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        root.addHandler(handler)
```

**PARTIAL SOLUTION:**

In my `setup_logging` function, I am using the following code:

```
    logging.basicConfig(filename=abs_log_file, level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
    root = logging.getLogger()
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    root.addHandler(console)
```

...and in the module that calls `setup_logging`, I have the following:

`# inhibits timestamps from printing to console
logging.getLogger('').handlers[1].formatter._fmt = '%(message)s'`

This works as desired, but I get the warning "Access to a protected member _fmt of a class".  What is a compliant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two handlers:

1. A handler named `handler`. The output stream for `handler` is `sys.stdout`. `handler` prints messages only, without time-stamps.
2. You have a handler named `console`. `console` prints time-stamp and message. You left the output stream unspecified.

Note that you did not pass anything into the constructor when you wrote, `console = logging.StreamHandler()` By default, the target of a StreamHandler is `sys.stderr` Neither of your handlers print to file. One prints to the console via `stdout` and the other prints to the console via `stderr`. I'm guessing that you are seeing time-stamps on the console from the `stderr` feed.

---

I recommend something like the following:

```
import logging
import sys

sysout = True
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("mylog.log", delay=True)
# If delay is true, then file opening
# is deferred until the first call to emit().
#
# there's no need to open the file until
# records are ready to be written
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
frmt_time_and_msg = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(frmt_time_and_msg)


if sysout:
    stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    msg_only = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    stdout_handler.setFormatter(msg_only)
    logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)


logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warning('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

Output seen on `sys.stdout`. Not that there are no time stamps:

```
info message
warn message
error message
critical message
```

The contents of `mylog.log`:

```
2019-11-06 17:24:55,502 - info message
2019-11-06 17:24:55,508 - warn message
2019-11-06 17:24:55,508 - error message
2019-11-06 17:24:55,508 - critical message
```